# If I shortcut an optimal TSP solution, is still optimal?

Tags: algorithm, graph, traveling-salesman

Let's have a complete undirected metric graph with k nodes; metric graph is a graph that satisfy the triangle inequality, so being w the weight function the for all nodes a, b, c it is true that w(a, c) is less or equal to w(a,b) + w(b,c).

Wlog let's say that the cycle: <1, 2, 3, ..., k, 1> is the optimal TSP solution for that graph.

My question is: if I remove one node from the graph (for example the n-th) and I shortcut the cycle just skipping n is the resulting cycle still an optimal TSP solution?

n.b., The cycle would become <1, 2, ..., n-1, n+1, ..., k, 1>

Comment: What would be more interesting (since the answer to this is clearly no): would any graph satisfying the triangle inequality have this property?

Comment: @PaulDraper doesn't a metric graph by definition satisfy the triangle inequality? I couldn't find a decent definition of metric graphs online. (For completeness: my interpretation of a metric graph is a plane graph for which the weight of an edge `(u, v)` is the Euclidean distance between `u` and `v`. Maybe that's totally wrong.)

Comment: @Heuster, you might be right. In that case, timrau's answer is incorrect, as 1->2->3 is shorter than 1->3. Paulo, could you clarify what a "metric graph" is?

Comment: Metric graph is a graph such that satisfy triangle inequality. So being w the weight function for every node a, b, c you have that w(a,b) + w(b,c) is more or equal than w(a,c). Edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this does not hold. A rather handwaving counterexample is given below. I trust you can add the numbers, do the math, and formally verify this (I used [this online solver](http://www.math.unl.edu/~jorr1/gilbhatch/tsp_applet.html) to verify my claims).

Consider these points:

[image]

The top point is clearly far away, so it has to be connected to the closest points. The other links then follow, as shown here:

[image]

If we exclude the top point, it is more optimal to have the two top points connect to the center point, as shown below. So just short-cutting is not optimal:

[image]